# Pedestal tutorial throws "Error processing request!" on (start)

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I followed the tutorial at https://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial/wiki/Getting-Started and did the following:

```
mkdir pedestal-app-tutorial
cd pedestal-app-tutorial
lein new pedestal-app tutorial-client no-comment
cd tutorial-client

v@mort:$ lein repl
    (at this point all the dependencies gets installed and then the repl starts)
    nREPL server started on port 37510 on host 127.0.0.1
     REPL-y 0.2.1
    Clojure 1.5.1
    Welcome to pedestal-app! Run (tools-help) to see a list of useful functions.
    user=> (start)

user=> (start)
:ok
```

Navigating to `http://localhost:3000/tutorial-client-dev.html` results in:

```
Error processing request!
Exception:

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match (Pattern.java:4615)
    java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match (Pattern.java:4466)
    java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match (Pattern.java:3694)
    etc, etc, etc ...
```

Clues, tips on what might have gone wrong?

Using Leiningen 2.3.2 and `project.clj` says: `io.pedestal/pedestal.app "0.2.1"`

Comment: What is Pedestal and Lein versions?

Comment: I'm using Leiningen 2.3.2 and project.clj says: io.pedestal/pedestal.app "0.2.1".  Also running java version "1.7.0_21" if that is of any help

Answer (score 0):

I cloned https://github.com/pedestal/app-tutorial and ran it without problems.

Later I accidentally `lein new pedestal-app ped-test` inside the `app-tutorial/` directory. Running the repl and `(start)` got I was happy to see that I could access the page on `localhost:3000`.

As a bonus I can now `lein new pedetestal-app` anywhere and it works.

Annoyingly I have no idea *why* it started working.

Comment: Blame it to the aliens! ;)

Comment: Grr...always those pesky aliens! :)